# Regex Style Pattern Matching in .NET Object Lists

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got a collection of .NET objects with various properties.  Lets say its a chain of Chromosomes in a genetic code - although the objects data is a little more complex than that.  I want to search the list for predefined sequences of objects.  I can define objects as a finite number of unique types of interest.  R,B,D and in a massive list I want to find certain sequences of objects:

A massively simplified version would be:

```
public class Chromosome {
    public ChromosomeType CromosomeType { 
       get {
        // Some logic that works out and returns the correct chromosome type

       }
    }
}

public enum ChromosomeType {
  R, B, D
}
```

So given a large collection of these types.  I want to match certain sequences

e.g.  `"R+B{3}D+"`

So in the "regex" above, the following subsequence would be matched in a list:
RRRBBBDD

I need to be able to return all matches from a very long list of Objects.

Clearly regex is perfect for this, but I don't actually have strings, I've got collections of objects.

Whats the best way to search a collection of objects for predefined sequences?

Update

Colin's solution is the one I went with in the end.  It works great.  I updated it to be able to handle multiple matches, and to use Arrays in order to be as fast as possible

Here's the final working solution:

```
    public static class ChromosomesExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Chromosome[]> FindBySequence(this Chromosome[] chromosomes, string patternRegex)
        {
            var sequenceString
                = String.Join(
                    String.Empty, //no separator
                    (
                        from c in chromosomes
                        select c.CromosomeType.ToString()
                    )
                );
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sequenceString, patternRegex);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Chromosome[] subset = new Chromosome[match.Value.Length];

                var j = 0;
                for (var i = match.Index; i < match.Index + match.Length; i++)
                {
                    subset[j++] = chromosomes[i];
                }
                yield return subset;
            }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            var chromosomes =
                new[]
                {
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 1},
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R, Id = 2 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R, Id = 3 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 4 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 5 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 6 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 7 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 8 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 9 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R, Id = 10 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R, Id = 11 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 12 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 13 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 14 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 15 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 16 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R, Id = 17 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R, Id = 18 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 19 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 20 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B, Id = 21 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 22 },
                    new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D, Id = 23 },
                };

            var matchIndex = 0;
            foreach (Chromosome[] match in chromosomes.FindBySequence("R+B{3}D+"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Match {++matchIndex}");
                var result = new String(match.SelectMany(x => string.Join("", $"id: {x.Id} Type: {x.CromosomeType.ToString()}\n")).ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
    Match 1
id: 2 Type: R
id: 3 Type: R
id: 4 Type: B
id: 5 Type: B
id: 6 Type: B
id: 7 Type: D
id: 8 Type: D

Match 2
id: 10 Type: R
id: 11 Type: R
id: 12 Type: B
id: 13 Type: B
id: 14 Type: B
id: 15 Type: D
id: 16 Type: D

Match 3
id: 17 Type: R
id: 18 Type: R
id: 19 Type: B
id: 20 Type: B
id: 21 Type: B
id: 22 Type: D
id: 23 Type: D
```

Comment: I am not quite clear. Is there a property that holds a value you are matching against or you want to apply regex on type name itself. Can you update question with your object structure.?

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding correctly, you could override `ToString()` to have it return whether that specific object is R,B, or D. Then, build up a string for the entire chain, and perform your `Regex` on that.

Comment: An example of your object would help.

Comment: I added an example of the type

Comment: @AlexGravely I thought of that but would like to avoid iterating through the collection and building a string if possible.  But yes that may turn out to be the most efficient way tbh.  Unless there's a  way to make a  collection of objects appear like a  string to the regex class?

Comment: @nikhilvartak question updated

Comment: @DVK  is this example  better?

Comment: I accomplished something using a simple extension method if that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, clean way using extension methods (that actually supports searching via Regex).

Classes:

```
public static class ChromosomesExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Chromosome> FindBySequence(this IEnumerable<Chromosome> chromosomes, string patternRegex)
    {
        var sequenceString
            = String.Join(
                String.Empty, //no separator
                (
                    from c in chromosomes
                    select c.CromosomeType.ToString()
                )
            );
        var match = Regex.Match(sequenceString, patternRegex);
        //returns empty if no match is found
        return chromosomes.ToList().GetRange(sequenceString.IndexOf(match.Value), match.Value.Length);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var chromosomes =
    new[]
    {
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.R },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.D },
        new Chromosome(){ CromosomeType = ChromosomeType.B },
    };

var queryResult = chromosomes.FindBySequence("R+B{3}D+");
```

Comment: This will return me individual objects who have Prop = R|B|D. But I want sequences of objects that conform to a pattern.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just skimmed your question. I'll tweak the answer.

Comment: I enhanced the question with an example

Comment: This looks good!! I will check it out properly tomorrow but looks like what I'm after!!! Cheers!!

Comment: Thank for the answer.  Its working great.  I tweaked your version a bit to make it faster and support multiple matches.  I posted the final version in the question - if you've got a any thoughts let me know.

Answer (score 1):

[Colin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37007601/1677912) seems to get you close to where you want to be. I have two thoughts to add:

1. Do you really need to pull in "RegEx" to accomplish the task? You're using a subset of the RegEx library for the quantifiers, but that is at the expense of adding a dependency to a complex tool. You may have a more portable application if you just make your own simple (albeit less flexible) syntax.
2. I would consider avoiding `ToString`, and simply give your objects a const string property that you could use to bounce the RegEx off of. If you're dealing with 'massive' amounts of data, it seems like calling ToString() everywhere would give you quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: Valid points. My code was certainly optimized for simplicity rather than performance, but I should note that FindBySequence() took about 0.6 seconds to crawl through a million chromosomes on my local dev box (0.2 if you started with a char vs. an enum). I'm not sure what performance or scale requirements the OP has, but my rule of thumb is to opt with simplicity over performance if the real-world impact is negligible. Also, I'm not sure that the OP was saying Regex was a requirement, I just utilized it to make the query easy to structure/understand .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but I have to answer.  I implemented ORegex engine (not for your problem, but very close to yours).
It's use is pretty much like you use Regex and will perfectly solve your problem with pattern matching on arbitary colletion. It is much faster than method above, and you can even pass some very complex condition fucntions (for example, check some object properties too). It is totaly free and available through Nuget.

**Example with prime sequences:**
[How to search patterns in arbitrary sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761014/lie-to-regex-or-how-to-illegaly-inherite-from-string)

**Project page with more examples:**https://github.com/eocron/ORegex