# Matching Patterns of Objects in F#

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have zero experience with F#.  I started reading [F# for C# Developers](https://www.amazon.co.uk/F-C-Developers-Developer-Reference-ebook/dp/B00JDMPL3W/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=) this weekend.

I had a problem recently (C# Code) where I had to search a list of .NET objects for subsets of objects that matched a certain pattern.

I described it as "regex style matching for objects" in the question.  And I did get a great solution that I was happy with, and which seems to perform quite well.

But my recent interest in F# lead me to wonder whether functional  programming might have an even better solution.

How would you solve this problem in F#?

[Regex Style Pattern Matching in .NET Object Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007478/regex-style-pattern-matching-in-net-object-lists)

Comment: Can you phrase your question more precisely? As is, it is way too broad.

Comment: I'm really not sure how I can phrase the question any differently than I have.... I had a problem in C#, I got a good solution (all the detail on the above link).  What's the equivalent F# solution?  Just trying to learn about F# and how it lends itself to problems like this....

Comment: I've read the linked question, but could you share the vocabulary you'd like to apply? Is `R+B{3}D+` the only sort of pattern you'd like to match, or do you need a richer vocabulary (e.g. grouping, alternates, etc.)?

Comment: Of interest: [How to implement simple finite state machines in F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/calculator-complete-v2/) This will give you an example of how much is involved. The significant change is adding [quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 4):

One interesting functional concept that might be useful here is [parser combinators](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/). The idea is that you use composable functions that describe how to read some input and then compose parsers for complex patterns from a couple of primitives.

Parsers normally work over strings, but there is no reason why you couldn't use the same method to read a sequence of chromosomes.

With parser combinators, you would rewrite the "regex" as a composition of F# functions. Something like:

```
sequence [ 
  zeroOrMore (chromosomeType R)
  repeat 3 (chromosomeType B)
  zeroOrMore (chromosomeType D) ]
```

This would give you a function that takes a list of chromosome objects and returns the parsed result - the subset of the list. The idea is that functions like `zeroOrMore` build parsers that detect certain patterns and you compose functions to build a parser - you get a function that you can just run on the input to parse it.

Explaining parser combinators is a bit too long for a SO answer, but it would probably be the most idiomatic F# approach to solving the problem.

Comment: Nice variation, however doesn't this still require the user to write and compile a separate sequence for each different input? The reason I suggested the OP stay with the RegEx version was so that they would not have to write and recompile code for each different input.

Comment: Was that a part of the question? Generally speaking, this looks a lot like scientific application, where the natural way of doing this in F# would be to use F# interactive & edit the code in a script file, rather than building some application for it.

Comment: OK. I can see a typical F# user doing that. Since the OP stated they just started with F# a few days ago maybe that should be in the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment posted as an answer because it is to long for a comment.

Since it seems that Regular Expressions are working for your problem and that you might suspect that F# [pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) or [active patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) might be a better solution I will add some understanding.

The input `R+B{3}D+` as I see it is a [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar), and as such will require a parser and evaluation engine, or the creation of something like a finite state machine. Since you know already that [.Net Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) can solve this problem, why go through all of the trouble to recreate this with F#. Even using F# pattern matching and active patterns will not be easier than using RegEx.

Thus the problem is basically to convert the C# code to F# code and make use of RegEx. So you are asking us to translate your C# to F# and that is not a valid SO question.

EDIT

As Mark Seemann noted in a comment the only input we have is `R+B{3}D+`. So if your actual grammar is more complicated than what RegEx can handle then there **might** be a better solution in F#.

Hopefully this helps you understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the other answers: Start by implementing a parser combinator allowing composition of the type `Parser<'a list>`. Add parsers for the minimal grammar required by `R+B{3}D+`.

```
type Result<'T> = Success of 'T | Failure
type Parser<'T> = Parser of ('T -> Result<'T * 'T>)

module ListParser =
    let (.>>.) (Parser f1) (Parser f2) =
        Parser <| fun input ->
            match f1 input with
            | Failure -> Failure
            | Success(value1, rest1) ->
                match f2 rest1 with
                | Failure -> Failure
                | Success(value2, rest2) -> 
                    Success(value1 @ value2, rest2)

    let oneOrMore what =
        let rec aux gotOne acc = function
        | x::xs when what = x -> aux true (x::acc) xs
        | xss when gotOne -> Success(List.rev acc, xss)
        | _ -> Failure
        Parser <| aux false []

    let exactly what n =
        let rec aux i acc = function
        | xss when i = 0 -> Success(List.rev acc, xss)
        | x::xs when what = x -> aux (i - 1) (x::acc) xs
        | _ -> Failure
        Parser <| aux n []
```

Finally create a function which will run the parser repeatedly until the input list is exhausted.

```
open ListParser
let runForall (Parser f) xss =
    let rec aux n acc xss =
        match xss, f xss with
        | [], _ -> List.rev acc
        | _::xs, Failure -> aux (n + 1) acc xs
        | _, Success(value, rest) ->
            aux (n + List.length value) ((n + 1, value)::acc) rest
    aux 0 [] xss

type ChromosomeType = R | B | D

[D;R;R;B;B;B;D;D;B;R;R;B;B;B;D;D;R;R;B;B;B;D;D]
|> runForall (oneOrMore R .>>. exactly B 3 .>>. oneOrMore D)
// val it : (int * ChromosomeType list) list =
//   [(2, [R; R; B; B; B; D; D]); (10, [R; R; B; B; B; D; D]);
//    (17, [R; R; B; B; B; D; D])]
```

Comment: A better way to read the input is to input it as a string then explode it into a string list. `let explode (s : string) : string list =
        let rec exap n l =
            if n < 0 then l
            else exap (n - 1) ((s.[n].ToString()) :: l)
        exap (String.length s - 1) []`

Comment: Yowzer this is gonna take some figuring out!!  Thanks for the answer!!